# RxJs split stream into multiple streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs, system.reactive

How can I split a never ending stream into multiple ending streams based on a grouping method?

```
--a--a-a-a-a-b---b-b--b-c-c---c-c-d-d-d-e...>
```

into these observables

```
--a--a-a-a-a-|
             b---b-b--b-|
                        c-c---c-c-|
                                  d-d-d-|
                                        e...>
```

As you can see, the `a` is at the beginning, and after I receive `b`, i will no longer get `a` so it should be ended. That's why the normal `groupBy` is not good.

Comment: Just for clarity, do you want an obserable that emits observables each time the sequence changes or do you want an observable that emits arrays of contiguous items?

Comment: The first. I want observables which emits values when the original emits. If the original has changed, (from `a` to `b`) then the observable of the `a` need to stop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `window` and `share` the source Observable. There's also a little trick with `bufferCount(2, 1)`:

```
const str = 'a-a-a-a-a-b-b-b-b-c-c-c-c-d-d-d-e';
const source = Observable.from(str.split('-'), Rx.Scheduler.async).share();

source
    .bufferCount(2, 1) // delay emission by one item
    .map(arr => arr[0])
    .window(source
        .bufferCount(2, 1) // keep the previous and current item
        .filter(([oldValue, newValue]) => oldValue !== newValue)
    )
    .concatMap(obs => obs.toArray())
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints (because of `toArray()`):

```
[ 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' ]
[ 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' ]
[ 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c' ]
[ 'd', 'd', 'd' ]
[ 'e' ]
```

The problem with this solution is the order of subscriptions to `source`. We need the `window` notifier to subscribe before the first `bufferCount`. Otherwise an item is first pushed further and then is checked whether it's different than the previous one with `.filter(([oldValue, newValue]) ...)`.

This means that be need to delay emission by one before `window` (that's the first `.bufferCount(2, 1).map(arr => arr[0])`.

Or maybe it's easier to control the order of subscriptions myself with `publish()`:

```
const str = 'a-a-a-a-a-b-b-b-b-c-c-c-c-d-d-d-e';
const source = Observable.from(str.split('-'), Rx.Scheduler.async).share();

const connectable = source.publish();

connectable
    .window(source
        .bufferCount(2, 1) // keep the previous and current item
        .filter(([oldValue, newValue]) => oldValue !== newValue)
    )
    .concatMap(obs => obs.toArray())
    .subscribe(console.log);

connectable.connect();
```

The output is the same.

Comment: yeah seems like we lost the very useful `publish(selector: Observable<T> => Observable<R>) : Observable<R>` overload of publish to simplify the subscription sharing.

Comment: @martin correct me if I'm wrong but in your first solution you delay the source observable more then actually needed. Instead of the bufferCount(2, 1).map(arr => arr[0]), I think you can use .delay(0)

Comment: Also, for keeping the previous and current item, you can replace the bufferCount(2, 1) with the more elegant pairwise() operator.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone can come up with something simpler but this works (fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/uk01njgc/) ...

```
let counter = 0;

let items = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
.map(value => Math.floor(value / 3))
.publish();

let distinct = items.distinctUntilChanged()
.publish();

distinct
.map(value => {
  return items
  .startWith(value)
  .takeUntil(distinct);
})
.subscribe(obs => {
  let obsIndex = counter++;
  console.log('New observable');
  obs.subscribe(
    value => {
      console.log(obsIndex.toString() + ': ' + value.toString());
    },
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Completed observable')
  );
});

distinct.connect();
items.connect();
```

Comment: Also, you could probably use `share` instead of `publish` saving you the hassle of the connect calls but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation that wraps up all the suscription sharing for you...

```
const stream = ...;

// an Observable<Observable<T>>
// each inner observable completes when the value changes
const split = Observable
  .create(o => {
    const connected = stream.publish();

    // signals each time the values change (ignore the initial value)
    const newWindowSignal = connected.distinctUntilChanged().skip(1);

    // send the observables to our observer
    connected.window(newWindowSignal).subscribe(o);

    // now "start"
    return connected.connect();
  });
```

Comment: it emits me `[a,a,a,a,b], [b,b,b,c]`

Answer (score 2):

```
import { from  } from 'rxjs'; 
import { share, window, map, publish, switchMap, 
         skip, toArray, distinct, bufferCount  } 
from 'rxjs/operators';


export function splitToArray(){
  const str = 'a-a-a-a-a-b-b-b-b-c-c-c-c-d-d-d-e-e';

  const lettters = from(str.split('-'))
    .pipe(
      share(),
      publish()
    );

  lettters
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(2, 1), 
    window(
      lettters
        .pipe(distinct(),
              skip(1)
            ),
    ),
      switchMap(obs => obs.pipe(
      map(([val1, val2]) => {return val1;}),
      toArray()))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

  lettters.connect();
}
```

My take on the issue. Using rxjs6 pipe function.

The trick here is to delay the elements as suggested by the @martin 
using bufferCount(2,1). So every element is emitted twice. Except the first one.
The big red arrows are moments on our timeline when new window is created. After that it is a simple matter of mapping the arrays of taking the first element of our double array.

[image]